# Does the Fifth Antinomy involve the indefinite/infinite distinction, just like the theoretical antinomies do?

Tags: kant, happiness

The Fifth Antinomy (FA) is the one from the second Critique, the one concerning the balance/harmony of virtue and happiness. As far as what I remember Kant saying goes, the FA doesn't pertain directly to infinitary questions. However, it occurred to me that Kant could have sustained the assertion, "Virtue ought to be infinite," or, "We ought to be infinitely virtuous," which when coupled with an assertion about the balance of happiness then yields, "There is a kind of happiness that ought to be infinite (in extent/intensity)." Here are some relevant quotes from the second Critique (not in order' also, this is the Thomas Kingsmill Abbott trans.):

> Morality began with the noblest attribute of human nature, the development and cultivation of which give a prospect of infinite utility...

> The worth of a character perfectly accordant with the moral law is infinite...

> The second, on the contrary, infinitely elevates my worth as an intelligence by my personality, in which the moral law reveals to me a life independent of animality and even of the whole sensible world, at least so far as may be inferred from the destination assigned to my existence by this law, a destination not restricted to conditions and limits of this life, but reaching into the infinite.

My claim about infinite happiness seems like one of those empirically ungroundable claims, such as are characteristic of the overall Kantian problematique of the antinomies. Could Kant parse the FA as a thesis (X<sub>0</sub>) that only a finite range of happiness is possible and an antithesis (X<sub>1</sub>) that infinite happiness is a necessary outcome, or even then (X<sub>1.1</sub>), that this necessary happiness exists in the thereby-authenticated [form of the divine nature](https://place.asburyseminary.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2730&context=faithandphilosophy)? This seems like it would "connect up" the function of the theoretical antinomies with the FA, with there being both an *idea* of happiness that is relatively inconsistent, and an *ideal* of happiness that is far too much to be accepted under the mandate of strict evidence (the proposition that we know that God is infinitely happy).

I do realize that Kant does not emphasize the happiness factor in the antinomy as it is emphasized in the above. One assumption I've come to make while reading Kant is that not even he necessarily/completely/absolutely understood every single detail of every sentence he ever wrote. He was no more ultimately self-omniscient than anyone else. But so for all that, I take it that when he assimilated the traditional types of moral theories under the fourfold heading that he did, and assimilated that to the heading of the theoretical categories to boot, he meant to say that moral theories that elevate happiness to the supreme principle are as deficient (or even ridiculous) as theories that say that anticipations of perception outrank axioms of intuition, analogies of experience, or postulates of modality (allowing that happiness, or also sadness, and other such things besides, are akin to anticipations of perception, whereas pleasure is akin to an intuition under an axiom, or then perfectionism depends on the categorical-hypothetical-disjunctive division and divine-command theory overexalts the necessity category).

So by contrast, emphasizing the impossibility of phenomenally infinite happiness in the set-up of the FA, is not to prioritize happiness in itself, in a principled form, above every other moral principle. So I don't expect that Kant would have denounced such an assertion as *false*. He might, though, have been wary of it, for a *moral* and not a normally factual reason: that attending to the FA in these terms would be to fall for a trick that Radical Evil likes to play on us, one that leads us to reiterate our inversion of our rational priorities.

Comment: Thankfully, Kant was not prone to the loose and promiscuous (mis)use of "infinite" that is so insufferably ubiquitous in philosophical demagoguery. It is ironic that the worst part of scholastics should cast the longest shadow. Figuring out what "extent/intensity" even mean as applied to virtue and happiness is the trap that utilitarians got themselves into, Kant had no need for that. Kant's goal was to resolve antinomies, why manufacture more of them with next to meaningless expressions like "infinite virtue" or "infinite happiness".

Comment: Per Zeno the cynic, virtue is simply binary which is mutually exclusive with vice in a same agent and cannot be increased or decreased. And happiness as a good flow of life only depends on moral actions, thus one's happiness could be said to be *infinite* in the same sense as the Bible talked about there's some water once drinked someone may *never* be thirsty...

Comment: @Conifold, I have added the material from the 2nd Critique that helped motivate my question. However, I am relying on the Thomas Kingsmill Abbott trans., and I have found here that citing the Meiklejohn trans. of the 1st Critique can lead me astray. Is there a similar problem with the TKA trans. here, or are the cited passages at least adequately translated?